# Aeson - simply decode ByteString -> Value

Tags: haskell

Sometimes Haskell can be really frustrating :) I'm searching for any function to simply convert ByteString into a Value. Everything seems to be only speaking about converting directly ByteString into a final type.

My reason to do this is to convert the JSON into Value and then "pre-extract" part of the Value that contains the "real data" and only pass the "real data" (one of many types) for specific type decoding so this part is not repeated in every parseJSON instance.

EDIT:
Thanks to everyone for answers, I forgot to show the real problem, maybe there is a better solution:

So, I'm building API client and the API returns everything wrapped in "data" object.

GET Dataset

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "WkzbQMuFYuamGv3YF",
    "name": "d7b9MDYsbtX5L7XAj",
    ...
  }
}
```

I parse this into

```
data Dataset = Dataset {
  name :: String,
  id :: String,
  ...
}
```

Then there is more complicated type of response with pagination
GET List Datasets

```
{
  "data": {
    "total": 2,
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 1000,
    "desc": false,
    "count": 2,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "WkzbQMuFYuamGv3YF",
        "name": "d7b9MDYsbtX5L7XAj",
        ...
      },
      ...
     ]
  }
}
```

For which I use more generic type as there is pagination of other things too

```
data PaginationList a = PaginationList {
    total :: Int,
    offset :: Int,
    limit :: Int,
    desc :: Bool,
    count :: Int,
    items :: [a]
} deriving Show
```

Now, this composes nicely and the Dataset inside parses automatically **except** for that "data" wrapper that I have to remove in every parsing. So this naive attempt doesn't work since in items :: [a] (where a becomes Dataset) I would try to unwrap every Dataset from "data".

Thus the solution I thought of is to pre-parse the JSON into Value to get rid of the "data" and then all the types will compose nicely.

Comment: You can use Hoogle to find a function by it's type.

https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%2Baeson%20ByteString%20-%3E%20Value

Comment: I have included the actual problem in the question, maybe someone has an even better approach in mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`Value`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.4.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value) *is* an instance of [**`FromJSON`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.4.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:FromJSON), so you can make use of [**`decode :: FromJSON a => ByteString -> Maybe a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.4.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:decode):

```
Prelude Data.Aeson> decode "{\"menu\": {\"id\": \"file\", \"value\": \"File\", \"popup\": {\"menuitem\": [1,4,2,5]}}}" :: Maybe Value
Just (Object (fromList [("menu",Object (fromList [("popup",Object (fromList [("menuitem",Array [Number 1.0,Number 4.0,Number 2.0,Number 5.0])])),("value",String "File"),("id",String "file")]))]))
```

So in fact there is nothing to define at all, you can use `decode` to decode to a `Value` as well. You however probably should specify the siganture to make that clear, so `decode "4" :: Maybe Value` for example.

The return type of decode is a `Maybe Value`, since it is not said that the `ByteString` you provided is a *valid* JSON stream. If you are absolutely sure it is valid JSON, you can use [**`fromJust :: Maybe a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust). But it is probably better to implement some sort of fallback mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is where I didn't see the elephant in the room :) BTW: I have included the actual problem in the question, maybe you have an even better approach in mind

Comment: @LukášKřivka: this actually looks like a use case to define a `FromJSON` like in the documentation: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.4.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html :) you can just specify how the JSON maps to your `PaginationList`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I have both instances for Dataset and PaginationList (should have included Gist).  The actual problem is that in ```parseJSON``` of Dataset I have to unwrap that "data". Then if I want to have ```fromJSON``` instance of Dataset to work automatically for inside PaginationList, it won't work because there is no "data" to unwrap. I could do ```case of``` but that feels dirty.

Answer (score 2):

> Everything seems to be only speaking about converting directly ByteString into a final type.

What makes "a finaly type" special?  Can `Value` be "final type"?

I think you're talking about the FromJSON class, which `Value` is already an instance.

You mention how Haskell can be frustrating and you've been searching for a function. Perhaps what you need isn't just a solution (`decode` as mentioned by @WillemVanOnsem) but also learning how to search.

**How to Search**

First, look at the documentation of [type you want and its instances](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.4.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value)  If you're at all familiar with the library you should recognize the important instances of ToJSON and FromJSON, which yield what you desire.

If the instances do not suffice then use Hoogle as Chris commented.  In this case you could tell hoogle to look just at Aeson and the type of the function you'd like: [`+aeson ByteString -> Value`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%2Baeson%20ByteString%20-%3E%20Value).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I appreciate it.